# How to avoid line wrap/centering in C# listbox control

Tags: c#, listbox, ownerdrawn

sorry if this has been asked, I was unable to find a solution after I searched google for about 3 days.

I'm a n00b, sorry.

With the little background on programming I have I managed to add a custom control from this project:
[FilesListBox from codeproject](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/12555/FilesListBox), the small program I'm trying to make is to manage sessions of files so that they can be opened in bulk, a general file session manager.

Anyway, my question is how can I customize the way the listbox's items strings are viewed, currently they are like this:
[image: wrong line presentation]

The final goal would be to open a txt file on the left, see the filenames listed on the listbox on the right and open them all at one with the default app

As of the code, I believe the important part is somewhere in here:

```
protected override void OnDrawItem(DrawItemEventArgs e)
    {
        e.DrawBackground();
        e.DrawFocusRectangle();
        Rectangle bounds = e.Bounds;
        if (e.Index > -1 && e.Index < Items.Count)
        {
            Size imageSize;
            string fileNameOnly = Items[e.Index].ToString();
            string fullFileName = GetFullName(fileNameOnly);
            Icon fileIcon = null;
            Rectangle imageRectangle = new Rectangle(bounds.Left + 1, bounds.Top + 1, ItemHeight - 2, ItemHeight - 2);
            if (fileNameOnly.Equals(".."))
            {
                // When .. is the string - draws directory icon                    
                fileIcon = IconExtractor.GetFileIcon(Application.StartupPath, _fileIconSize);
                e.Graphics.DrawIcon(fileIcon, imageRectangle);
            }
            else
            {
                fileIcon =
                    IconExtractor.GetFileIcon(fullFileName, _fileIconSize);
                // Icon.ExtractAssociatedIcon(item);
                e.Graphics.DrawIcon(fileIcon, imageRectangle);
            }
            imageSize = imageRectangle.Size;
            fileIcon.Dispose();


            Rectangle fileNameRec = new Rectangle(bounds.Left + imageSize.Width + 3, bounds.Top, bounds.Width - imageSize.Width - 3, bounds.Height);
            StringFormat format = new StringFormat();
            format.LineAlignment = StringAlignment.Center;
            e.Graphics.DrawString(fileNameOnly, e.Font, new SolidBrush(e.ForeColor),
                fileNameRec, format);
        }

        base.OnDrawItem(e);
    }
```

The full code of the class can be obtained on the codeproject page, but I paste the full code here: [full FilesListBox.cs](https://pastebin.com/CxngjaCx) anyway, maybe a kind soul can take a look.

Comment: `format.FormatFlags = StringFormatFlags.NoWrap;` Also check `format.Alignment` for horizontal alignment.

Comment: Wow that works really great ! Many thanks @JQSOFT, is there a way to add a tooltip to see the full name ? Also, how can I see the options or the usage of `format.Alignment` ? I really appreciate it :)

Comment: For example: `format.Alignment = StringAlignment.Near` for left align. See the other options. As for the the tooltip, yes it possible but needs some code to write. However it's out of the scope of this post. You need to post a new one regarding the tooltip issue.

Comment: Many thanks, this can be marked as solved :)

Comment: Most welcome mate.